# Trouble porting MQL4 for loop to Pinescript

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5

Well, I taught myself MQL4/C++ (enough to get around in it at least) and I'm trying to transfer an indicator I built over to TradingView. I'm having trouble wrapping my head around the syntax differences though.

Here's the MQL4 loop

```
for(int i=limit; i>=1; i--)
{
if(KBuffer[i]>80 || KBuffer[i]<20)   CrossoverValue=KBuffer[i];
else if(KBuffer[i]>CrossoverValue)  BuyBuffer[i]=100;
else if(KBuffer[i]<CrossoverValue)  SellBuffer[i]=100;
if(KBuffer[i]>CrossoverValue)  EntryCondition[i]=1; //1=Buy
if(KBuffer[i]<CrossoverValue)  EntryCondition[i]=2; //2=Sell
}
```

and here's what I've got so far in Pine

```
for i = 1 to 100
if k[i] > 80 or k[i] < 20
    crossoverValue = k[i]
else if k[i] > crossoverValue
    buyBuffer[i] = 100
else k[i] < crossoverValue
    sellBuffer[i] = 100
if k > crossoverValue
    entryCondition := 1
if k< crossoverValue
    entryCondition := -1
```

I know I'm not getting the Pine syntax right, but after doing a bunch of googling and reading the Pine manual I'm still struggling.

Currently I'm getting a *Mismatched input 'if' expecting 'end of line without line continuation'.* error.

Any pointers as to where I'm going wrong would be really appreciated!

For reference, here's a screenshot of the MT4 version. It's delivering a buy signal when the Stochastic K line has crossed above 20 and is below 80, and vice versa.

[image: Stochastic RSI buy/sell signals]

Answer (score 0):

You're almost there
Documentation: https://www.tradingview.com/pine-script-reference/v5/#op_for

```
for i = limit to 0 by -1
   if k[i] > 80 or k[i] < 20
     crossoverValue = k[i]
  else if k[i] > crossoverValue
     buyBuffer[i] = 100
  else k[i] < crossoverValue
     sellBuffer[i] = 100

  if k > crossoverValue
    entryCondition := 1
  if k< crossoverValue
    entryCondition := -1
```

"For reference, here's a screenshot of the MT4 version. It's delivering a buy signal when the Stochastic K line has crossed above 20 and is below 80, and vice versa."

Maybe use the standard stochastic indicator then?

```
//@version=5
indicator(title="Stochastic", shorttitle="Stoch", format=format.price, precision=2, timeframe="", timeframe_gaps=true)
periodK = input.int(14, title="%K Length", minval=1)
smoothK = input.int(1, title="%K Smoothing", minval=1)
periodD = input.int(3, title="%D Smoothing", minval=1)
k = ta.sma(ta.stoch(close, high, low, periodK), smoothK)
d = ta.sma(k, periodD)

buy = ta.crossover(k, 20)
sell = ta.crossunder(k, 80)

plot(k, title="%K", color=#2962FF)
plot(d, title="%D", color=#FF6D00)

plotshape(buy, title = "Buy", shape = shape.triangleup, location = location.belowbar, size = size.normal, color = color.green)

plotshape(sell, title = "Sell", shape = shape.triangledown, location = location.abovebar, size = size.normal, color = color.red)

h0 = hline(80, "Upper Band", color=#787B86)
hline(50, "Middle Band", color=color.new(#787B86, 50))
h1 = hline(20, "Lower Band", color=#787B86)
fill(h0, h1, color=color.rgb(33, 150, 243, 90), title="Background")
```

Comment: Thanks for the input. I was quite a bit off – see my answer below.

And yes, I have been working off of the default TV sRSI indicator.

Answer (score 0):

Here's what I ended up with – the 'or' operator in the first if statement wasn't working for some reason, so I had to split it up, and a number of other syntactical things.

```html
var float crossoverValue = 0
for i = 0 to 0
    if k[i] > 80
        crossoverValue := k[i]
    else if k[i] < 20
        crossoverValue := k[i]
entryCondition = if k > crossoverValue
    color.green
else if k < crossoverValue
    color.red
else
    #9598a1
```

Note: the code editor is massacring my line breaks when I try to paste it into the basic 'curly brackets' type. I have to use the JS/HTML/CSS block for some reason.

Answer (score 0):

Oh. Turns out I don't need a for loop at all!

I'm so used to using them in MT4.

Here's the actual final result.

```html
var float crossoverValue = 0
if k > 80
    crossoverValue := k
else if k < 20
    crossoverValue := k
entryCondition = if k > crossoverValue
    color.green
else if k < crossoverValue
    color.red
else
    #9598a1
```